# Store result of DIR without file extension in Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

The task is simple, or so it seems, but not sure how I can *pipe the substring operation* to the *dir command* in windows batch script.

Let's suppose I have something like:

```
dir /b /on "C:\MyFolder" | findstr _in_ > temp.txt
```

This would put all the filenames to the temp.txt file, only I don't need the file extensions.

I know the substring operation for this would be something like:

```
"%myvar:~0,-4"
```

But how do I combine the two?

I also don't understand how this substring operation would work on batch variables with two `%%`.

Thanks!

Comment: `for %%a in ("C:\MyFolder\*" ) do echo %%~na`

Comment: Ah, and I can just pipe the findstr at the very end of this... that was my problem with the for before, I could not add the pipe, but now I realised I can just add it to the end. Thanks!

Comment: Well actually if you switch to using a `FOR/F` command you can use your original code within the `IN` clause.

Comment: `For %A In ("C:\MyFolder\*_in_*") Do @(Echo %~nA)>>"temp.txt"` or if the order is important to you, `For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Dir /B/ON/A-D "C:\MyFolder\*_in_*" 2^>Nul') Do @(Echo %~nA)>>"temp.txt"`